# setup:static-content:deploy NOT UPDATE

Tags: theme, magento2.2

I'm using Magento 2.2.2 & Redis, I have others language store in my Magento.

I edited the `app/fronted/(theme)` `.phtml` file and then ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` or `php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy en_US`, but no update.

I already deleted it, but that didn't work either.

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
rm -rf pub/static/_cache
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml
rm -rf pub/static/deployed_version.txt
```

How can I update it?

Comment: Please  set the static sign option to no in store > configuration > developer static sign and reply again after remove content as you mention in your post

Answer (score 2):

You must run below commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The second command clears the Redis cache if it is configured properly.

You no need run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language en_US`, because you edited the `phtml` file, not `less`, `js`, `html` files.

If you no see any modification, it is possible to use opcache, you must check that.

Answer (score 1):

**`static-content:deploy`** sometimes doesn't seem to take effect and apply your changes (like adding your `custom css` in the layout and other modifications) unless you run first the **`setup:upgrade`** command.

Answer (score 0):

If you created **multiple store views (languages)**, you should be able to generate the files by running the following *command in cli* and **while logged in as file system owner**:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

There is a button for it as well in admin Cache Management if you're in developer or default mode.

**There is also a bug in static content deploy when you have multiple languages.** The bug impacts CSS and language for translated sites. The workaround is to deploy each language for each theme separately. Not in the same command.

Example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma en_US

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma nl_NL

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma fr_FR
```

Read more about it [here at GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7862).

Comment: i'm using production mode,but run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy just only have update en_us..have not others language file in fronted..and when i edit theme file in app/...  not update in pub/static/.. file too.

Comment: updated in the post

Comment: Did you clear cache after static content deploy?

Comment: YES, but no work

Comment: Check the editted answer from user5198077. Seems there's a bug in Magento 2.2 for multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following command to deploy static content for multiple languages:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

OR

```
php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command for update:

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try this steps

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.
  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*`

`rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*`